# IDisposable interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface, idisposable

I was learning C# and I read about an interface called IDisposable with the only method Dispose() calling it by using the using syntac.
If I use the following:

```
Class b=new Class();
using(b)
{
//statements
}

using (Class o=new Class())
{
//statements
}
```

What will happen if I try to use the objects b and o after the braces have ended in both the cases?

Comment: With some luck, usually available, you'll be slapped with an ObjectDisposedException to remind you that you did it wrong.

Comment: Why not try it and find out.  The second example is the easy one to test, the first can vary a bit between classes, but you should get a basic idea with just a handful of tests.

Answer (score 5):

`b` will still be in scope and not null, but most well implemented classes that dispose *should* throw an exception if you try to use them after they have had `Dispose` called (thus stopping you from using it further).

It will compile and may still be usable - it entirely depends on how it has been implemented internally. However, you **shouldn't** use it as it's state is not guaranteed and creates confusing code.

`o` will be out of scope and won't compile.

All the `using` statement does is cause the compiler to emit some `try-catch` statements and  call `Dispose` on the wrapped object. It does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the object later, you dont have to use the using block. its recommended to use it but in some cases you can use the following structure:

```
class b = null;
try
{
  b = new class();

  /* ... do your stuff ... */

}
catch (Exception)
{
  /* handle errors */  
  throw;
}
finally
{
  if (b != null)
  {
    b.Dispose();
    b = null;
  }            
}
```

this way b will be disposed at the end of your method if exists.

you are also allowed to have a using block inside a using block:

```
using (Class a=new Class())
{
  /* you can access a here */
  using (Class b=new Class())
  {
    /* you can access a and b here  */
  }
}
```